# Pattern to avoid the need for Downcasting/Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, abstraction, downcast

Suppose I have two implementations of a base class:

```
public class Base { 
    public string Stringify() { return "I am a member of base class"; }
}

public class A : Base {
    public void DoAThing() {...};
}

public class B : Base {
    public void DoBThing(int anInteger) {...};
}
```

Suppose I want to put many instances of `Base` in a list, so that I can loop over them and call `Stringify()` on each, and make use of their shared functionality.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    A thing1 = new A();
    B thing2 = new B();
    B thing3 = new B();     
    List<Base> list = new List<Base> {thing1, thing2, thing3};
    foreach(Base base in list) { Console.WriteLine(base.Stringify()); }           
}
```

Now suppose there are many many `Base` objects, such that maintaining the individual `thing` references to each one is not realistic. Would there be any way, via only the list, to regain the `DoAThing()` or `DoBThing()` functionality that is lost by the abstraction without having to use explicit downcasting and reflection?

This feels like it would be a common enough occurance, so I am wondering if there is a design flaw or established pattern I am missing here that would help in this situation.

Comment: At the moment, `DoAThing` and `DoBThing` have a different signature, so it isn't really clear what you mean, but *in general* this sounds like a job for an `abstract` method, a `virtual` method, or an `interface`. You don't show how you intend to use `DoAThing` / `DoBThing` - can you clarify?

Comment: That's the idea, that the two methods I intend to use differ in signature, so I can't use inheritance to solve the problem.
In essence my question is: If objects only share some of their functionality, how can I store them in a collection without losing access to the specific functionality?

Comment: You could use the visitor pattern although that can be quite verbose.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you would do this using something like downcasting?  There are a couple of approaches that could be taken here but it's hard to recommend one without a more concrete example of how you want to use the `DoXThing` methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you debug, you can notice every object of the list mantains its' class.

This way:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A thing1 = new A();
        B thing2 = new B();
        B thing3 = new B();
        List<Base> list = new List<Base> { thing1, thing2, thing3 };
        foreach (Base bas in list) {
            Console.WriteLine(bas.Stringify());

            if(bas is A)
            {
                ((A)bas).DoAThing();
            }
            else if (bas is B)
            {
                ((B)bas).DoBThing(1);
            }
            else
            {
                //IDK
            }
        }
    }

}

public abstract class Base
{
    public string Stringify() { return "I am a member of base class"; }
}

public class A : Base
{
    public void DoAThing()
    {

    }
}

public class B : Base
{
    public void DoBThing(int anInteger)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this downcasting?

Comment: Downcasting is an operation that creates a subclass reference from a base class reference.

Comment: Which is what you're doing with `((A)bas)`

Comment: @Lee yes you are right. I tought doing it via interface instead of class would make a difference for the OP